# Particular solution to the matrix form Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

This question is more for general understanding than looking for a specific answer.

I have a theorem that states:

"If Ax=b has a solution x$_p$, then the general solution to the equation is x$_p$ + x$_0$, where x$_0$ ranges over Ker(A)."

I understand that this means the general solution would be x$_p$ + a$_1$x$_1$ + a$_2$x$_2$ + ... + a$_k$x$_k$. However, I keep seeing x$_p$ being referred to as a *particular solution*. Does *particular solution* mean that x$_p$ is a *unique solution* or does it mean that x$_p$ is simply *a single* solution, possibly amongst an infinite number of solutions? And if it is one of an infinite number of solutions, does it mean we can pick *any* x$_p$ and add it to x$_n$ where x$_n\in$ Ker(A) to get a general solution?

I hope that makes sense and thank you for any clarification you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a unique solution if and only if the kernel is trivial, i.e., $\ker A=\{0\}$. In this case, $x_p$ is the only solution.

Otherwise, there are many solutions, and you can take $x_p$ to be any specific one of them; your theorem tells how to get all of the other solutions. For each element $x_{ker}\in\ker A$, the quantity $x_p +x_{ker}$ is another solution, and all solutions are of this form (including, incidentally, $x_p$ itself, since it can be written as $x_p+ 0$ and surely $0\in\ker A$).

**Note:** This assumes we are dealing with a field of scalars, not just a ring in general. The situation is a little different in that case.

Comment: You're assumption was right and your answer is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome ${}{}{}{}$